# What is wrong with my website?

Tags: css

On my website I have product listings on the home page.

The product listings aren't lining up properly. The second product is showing slightly lower than the first and so forth.

Please tell me what CSS I need to add or delete. Any Suggestions?

Site: http://melbourne-plumber.com/

Comment: please post u r code here

Comment: Show us your relevant code or a separate short example of the problem.

Comment: pls share your fiddle code

Comment: But that looks cool, why do you want to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with the `pre` tag you are using in html :

**what you are using is** : `<pre class="brush: php; gutter: false">`

**what you should use** : `<div class="brush: php; gutter: false">`

This can solve your issue.